# Populating JavaFX ComboBox or ChoiceBox from enum

Tags: java, combobox, enums, javafx

Is there a way to populate a JavaFX `ComboBox` or `ChoiceBox` with all enumerations of a enum ?

Here is what I tried :

```
public class Test {

    public enum Status {
        ENABLED("enabled"),
        DISABLED("disabled"),
        UNDEFINED("undefined");

        private String label;

        Status(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return label;
        }
    }
}
```

In a another class, I'm trying to populate a `ComboBox` :

```
    ComboBox<Test.Status> cbxStatus = new ComboBox<>();
    cbxStatus.setItems(Test.Status.values());
```

But I get an error : `incompatible types: Status[] cannot be converted to ObservableList<Status>`

I obviously get the same problem with a `ChoiceBox`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If setItems requires an ObservableList, then you have to give it one instead of an array.

Try this:

```
ComboBox<Status> cbxStatus = new ComboBox<>();
cbxStatus.setItems( FXCollections.observableArrayList( Status.values()));
```

Edit: The solution of James_D (see comment) is the preferred one:

```
cbxStatus.getItems().setAll(Status.values());
```

Comment: or `cbxStatus.getItems().setAll(Status.values());`

Comment: Oh yes, that one is better :D

Comment: James_D solution is my chosen one ! Thnx

Comment: any way to do it from FXML?

Comment: It doesn't make a big deal of difference, but `cbxStatus.getItems().setAll(Arrays.asList(Status.values()));` will avoid a warning that reads "non-varargs call of varags method".

Answer (score 6):

I used FXML for this. My enum has a constructor

```xml
<ComboBox GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
     <items>
         <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
             <Type fx:value="ABC"/>
             <Type fx:value="DEF"/>
             <Type fx:value="GHI"/>
         </FXCollections>
     </items>
</ComboBox>
```

---

```java
public enum Type {
    ABC("abc"), 
    DEF("def"), 
    GHI("ghi");

    private String name;

    private Type(String theType) {
        this.name = theType;
    }
}
```

Comment: An arguably more elegant solution would be to use `fx:constant`, so it directly references the enum values rather than rely on the static `valueOf` method. Some editors may even provide completion when using `fx:constant`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to:

```
ComboBox<Status> cbxStatus = new ComboBox<>();
cbxStatus.getItems().setAll(Arrays.asList(Status.values()));
```