# How do I populate a ChoiceBox from an Enum?

Tags: javafx, enums

I'm trying to do something that seems simple but am getting very confused because it doesn't seem to work.

I am using Java 8 and am trying to populate a JavaFX ChoiceBox with the values in an Enum I created called AgencyCodes. I researched this issue here at stackOverflow and found this: 
[Populating JavaFX ComboBox or ChoiceBox from enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801119/populating-javafx-combobox-or-choicebox-from-enum)

When I try to imitate the two solutions in that article, both the preferred one and the other one, I get compile errors because setItems() and setAll() expect a String[], not the ObservableList claimed in the article. Is the article just flat-out wrong? Or has the API changed in the last year?

I can use a for loop to read out the values in the enum and then stuff them into a String array but it's tedious because enum seems to lack any method for determining the number of values in the enum. At least I don't see anything in the API. Is there some simple way to get the number of constants in the enum or do I have to count them with a for loop? Is there no simpler way to put the values in the enum into a ChoiceBox?

My enum is pretty simple:

```
public enum AgencyCode {

    TW ("TorontoWonder"), 
    CPA ("Canadian Pacific Airways"), 
    Elem ("Elementary"); 

    private final String agencyName;

    AgencyCode (String agencyName) {
        this.agencyName = agencyName;
    }

    public String getAgencyName() {
        return agencyName;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("The code and full name of each agency are: ");
        for (AgencyCode ac : AgencyCode.values()) {
            System.out.println(ac + " - " + ac.getAgencyName() );
        }
    }
}
```

The code I have to put enum contents into the ChoiceBox is:

```
    String[] agencyCodes = new String[3];
    int ix = 0;
    for (AgencyCode ac : AgencyCode.values()) {
        System.out.println(ac + " - " + ac.getAgencyName());
        agencyCodes[ix] = ac.toString();
        ix++;
    }

    ChoiceBox<String> ticketAgency = new ChoiceBox<String>();
    ticketAgency.getItems().setAll(agencyCodes);
               //ticketAgency.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(AgencyCode.values()));
    grid.add(ticketAgency, 1, 3);
```

Any guidance you could give me on this point would be appreciated. I can't believe I need to resort to such a technique to simply populate a ChoiceBox.

Comment: Why are you using a `ChoiceBox<String>`, instead of a `ChoiceBox<AgencyCode>`? The code from the linked question works fine when you make that change.

Comment: James_D, you're absolutely right. I didn't pick up on the fact that you had the type of the ChoiceBox set to STATUS in your example. I think I just assumed that ChoiceBox would have to contain Strings and simply didn't see that you'd done it differently.

Comment: That's just what the parameter type of a `ChoiceBox` means: the type of the objects that it contains. If you make it a `ChoiceBox<String>` you have to put `String`s in it. (That's exactly what the error message is telling you.) If you want to put `AgencyCode`s in it, you need it to be a `ChoiceBox<AgencyCode>`.