# How to fill JavaFX ChoiceBox with seprate Enum Class?

Tags: java, sql, database, javafx, enums

I am trying to create a JavaFX program to manage a production line. I am working with a database so that the user can populate a database with `TextField` and `ChoiceBox`. I am having trouble filling a `ChoiceBox` from an Enum class that I have created.

It is expected that my `ChoiceBox` is populated with items from my `Enum` class, however, the `ChoiceBox` is staying blank. The code is compiling.

Before you refer me to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801119/populating-javafx-combobox-or-choicebox-from-enum), I have tried using the advice in that discussion, but I am unable to wrap my head around it. That discussion does not help because I am not sure where they are trying to populate their `ComboBox`. Also, `cbxStatus.getItems().setAll(Status.values());` is not working for me (I might be applying it incorrectly).

My Enum class:

```
package sample;

public enum ItemType {
    AUDIO("AU"),
    VISUAL("VI"),
    AUDIOMOBILE("AM"),
    VISUALMOBILE("VM");

    final String itemType;

    ItemType(String itemType) {
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }

    public String getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }
}
```

My Controller class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private TextField productName;
    @FXML
    private TextField productManufacturer;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<ItemType> itemType = new ChoiceBox<>();

    private DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();

    public Controller() throws SQLException {
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        itemType.getItems().setAll(ItemType.values());
    }

    public void addProduct() {
        String name = productName.getText();
        String manufacturer = productManufacturer.getText();
        String type = itemType.toString();

        databaseManager.insert(type, manufacturer, name);
        System.out.println("Button Pressed");
    }

    public void recordProduction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Button Pressed");
    }
}
```

Lastly, once the `ChoiceBox` is populated, I need to capture the user's choice to input into my database. Something like `String type = itemType.toString();`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the obvious and thinking the new thing, the `Enum` is the problem.

```
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<ItemType> itemType = new ChoiceBox<>();
```

Your controller's field has access to one ChoiceBox instance and the one on the form is a different one. You never added your items to the choicebox you interact with.

Comment: How can I do that and where I should I do that?

Comment: Just remove the creating the choicebox, it will be injected when the FXML is loaded. `= new ChoiceBox<>()`